# Execute multiple commands in .sh file in Linux

Tags: bash, recursion, command-line, diff, glob

I am trying to create a diff file the following way:

```
hdiff.pl -nx $FILEDIR/*filename* *filename* > diff_*filename*
```

However I need to run this command on 150 different files to create 150 different diff files. I am attempting to write a script to execute that will create all of the files for me but I am not sure what to put so that the command is recursive and uses all of the files in the directory.

I tried making a script to execute but it is looking like I just have to write out every individual command and then execute the script.

Edit:

To clarify, I am trying to avoid writing 150 lines of this:

```
hdiff.pl -nx $FILEDIR/*filename1* *filename1* > diff_*filename1*
hdiff.pl -nx $FILEDIR/*filename2* *filename2* > diff_*filename2*
hdiff.pl -nx $FILEDIR/*filename3* *filename3* > diff_*filename3*
```

Comment: When you say `*filename1*`, do you mean that as a glob, or a standin for a specific filename? `*`s are shell syntax, so trying to use them as formatting is a fast route to confusion; `*filename*` isn't a generic "insert a filename here" signifier; instead, it means "insert a list of all the filenames that have 'filename' inside them here".

Comment: *filename1* is just a placeholder. The real file names look more like this: T_FILE_NAME

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're after something along these lines:

```
for f in *filename*; do
  hdiff.pl -nx "${FILEDIR}/${f}" "${f}" > "diff_${f}"
done
```

Note that that expands *one* glob expression to get a list of subject files, and uses each one (in turn, via a loop) to form the names of the corresponding files in the command you want to run.

Comment: As I read the question, _finding_ the filenames to iterate over requires globing inside "$FILEDIR"`; so we probably need to be including it in the glob and then stripping it out, as opposed to globbing without it and then extending.

Comment: It's hard to be sure, @CharlesDuffy, but the example command in the question seems to assume that there are matching input files in the working directory and in `$FILEDIR`, in which case one can work from either set.

Answer (score 1):

Using bash globbing with a loop and some bash parameter expansions:

```
#!/bin/bash

for f in "$filedir"/* ; do 
    hdiff.pl -nx "$f" "${f##*/}" > "diff_${f##*/}" ;
done
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have them in two separate directories, you could try the following:

```
#!/bin/bash

set -e

SRCDIR=$1 # $FILEDIR/filename
DSTDIR=$2 # filename

for FILE in $1/*; do hdiff.pl -nx $1/$FILE $2/$FILE > diff_$FILE ; done
```

Save as `rundiff.sh` and then you could simply `$ ./rundiff.sh directory1 directory2`

You may want to do some extra tweaking to the above if you want to print each file name while processing, and sanity checking inputs.

Comment: `set -e` -- so as soon as one file fails we want to stop there and not process any more?

Comment: (if that's what we really want, think about putting an explicit `|| exit` after the failing command to make it clear to the reader; explicit error handling also avoids all the implicit, surprising behavior described in [BashFAQ #105](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/105#Exercises))

Comment: `diff_$FILE` looks odd.

Comment: @Cyrus, ...the only thing obviously wrong with `diff_$FILE` is that it'll have the directory name in it, as opposed to `"diff_${FILE##*/}"`

Comment: (of course, one can also argue that using all-caps names for application-defined variables is obviously wrong in and of itself, contravening [black-letter POSIX specifications](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap08.html))